# RStudio: Show workspace isn't working

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using R studio, and selecting the menu option 'Show workspace' does nothing. Nor does Ctl + 8. I just have a console, running fine, but with no workspace, plots, file windows available. They're not greyed out in the drop down menu... and I don't get an error. They just don't work. Prior to this starting, I had cleared the workspace, then closed it, now it won't reopen. Any help would be huge...

Comment: May be its hidden. Try dragging your panels to see if it is hidden. You can try ls() to see if there are any objects.in the workspace.

Comment: am I that green? Good God. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Comment changed to answer to solve and close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be its hidden. Try dragging your panels to see if it is hidden. You can try ls() to see if there are any objects.in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.2 of RStudio it seems that Workspace view/tab is called Environment. To view your variables select 'Global Environment' in the dropdown right beneath